# How to DRYly watch a $resource for updates?

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource, ngresource

I have an angular app that has a controller. The controller loads a resource, made from the $resource service, and exposes a function for a button on the html template to update the lead. The code looks something like

```
app
.service('User', function($resource){
  return $resource(...);
})
.controller('FooController', function($scope, User){
  var doSomething = function(){...};

  $scope.user = User.get(1);
  $scope.user.$promise.then(function(){
    doSomething();
  });

  $scope.save = function(){
    $scope.user.$save()
    .then(function(){
      doSomething();
    });
  };
})
```

My question is: is there a DRY way to state once that `doSomething` should be called whenever the user gets its updated data, whether it's from a `get` or a `save`?

Answer (score 0):

yes you can use $watch function on $scope.user and call your doSomething function.

Something like this

```
$scope.$watch('$scope.user',function(newVal,oldVal){
 //your code here
});
```

Comment: `$scope.user.$save()` doesn't change the reference that `$scope.user` points to.

Comment: $watching $scope.user is not helpful, because $scope.user is still the same object after a call to $scope.user.$save. the members of $scope.user change, but $scope.user itself is still the same object.

Comment: $scope.$watch('$scope.user',function(){},true) will deep watch the object.

Comment: I want to be notified when, and only when, the object's data is loaded from the remote server. deep-watching the object doesn't know if a member changed because it was loaded from the server, or because the app changed it e.g. as a result of user input.